# meteor return asynchronously data to helper

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I have this helper, which call a google api function( getDistance) that returns it asynchronously, so for the help it's undefined.
How can I update the helper when result arrive?

Thanks.

```
distanceIs: function (destination){
            var origin = Session.get('userLatLng');
            var isDistance =  Blaze._globalHelpers.getDistance(origin, [destination[0], destination[1]] );
            return isDistance;

    }
```

Comment: You should rather call the Google API in `onCreated`, and when you get back the result you put it in a reactive variable (for example `Session`). Your `distanceIs` helper should then simply return the value stored in this reactive variable (it will re-run when the value in the reactive variable changes).

Comment: i can't do this, because the helper is rendered on each item that is displayed. e.g I have a list of items rendered and on each item I have the helper {{distanceIs destination}}.

Comment: Use an additional template that renders one item.

Comment: Could you explain a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a reactive variable that is updated.

```
Template.map.onCreated(function () {
  this._distance = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.map.helpers({
  distanceTo() {
    const origin = Session.get('userLatLng');
    someAsynchronousFunction(origin, (err, res) => this._distance.set(res));
  }
  getDistance() {
    return this._distance.get();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is there no problem with one var for many requests, which are asynchronous?

Comment: Then they would be overwritten, if that's okay

Comment: it's ok, but i don't know which is returning for which...
Can I do something like that?Assuming i will pass _id from each item.: this._distance._id.set(res));

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having something like this:

```html
<template name="map">
  {{#each getDestinations}}
    {{distanceIs this}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Change it into:

```html
<template name="map">
  {{#each getDestinations}}
    {{> distance}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="distance">
  {{getDistance}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.distance.onCreated(function(){
  this.distance = new ReactiveVar(0)
  var self = this
  googleAPI.getDistance("Point A", "PointB", funciton(result){
    self.distance.set(result.distance)
  })
})
Template.distance.helpers({
  getDistance: function(){
    return Template.instance().distance.get()
  }
})
```

Note: in order to use `ReactiveVar` you must add the `reactive-var` package.

Comment: Yes, but reactive-dict is required, because if there are 100s calls to the google api, you don't know in what order they will return. Each request has to have it's own id. Right?

Comment: With this solution, each request will have its own `ReactiveVar` instead.